# Can't start Ubuntu after interrupted upgrade

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, data-recovery, startup, 16.10

I was trying to upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, but during the upgrade process an error popped up (it said something like 'there is an error in system files' but I don't remember exactly).

The upgrade window froze and I forced quit.

Now, after restart Ubuntu is stuck at purple screen. What should I do to reach the login screen? I have important files in my system and now I can't reach them also. I also have windows 8 installed pc and I can start windows normally, if that's any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alright, let's do this:**

What you'll need:

- 2 flash drives
- Another computer (or another working OS on your computer)

Here are the steps:

1. On the other OS or computer, navigate to [the Ubuntu download page,](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and download Ubuntu 16.04.1
2. Burn the ISO to a flash drive using a program such as [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/). (If you're using Rufus, your window should look like [image: this]
3. Once that's done, **reboot**!
4. Get to the boot menu (before your computer launches Windows, while the computer's logo is still showing), typically by pressing F12. (If that doesn't work, check your computer manufacturer's support.
5. Navigate to the flash drive you just created. (Using arrow keys) Most likely called Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS amd64 or Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS or something along those lines.
6. It'll boot up to a Ubuntu installation environment. (It might have a few options before, like a menu, just press enter. This is a selection of what you want to start to.)
7. Select the live option.
8. Open up the file explorer, find your files, and move them on to the other USB **DO NOT PUT THE FILES ON THE USB YOU USED TO PUT UBUNTU ON!**
9. Open up the installer (on the desktop), and follow the instructions.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I moved my files to usb before your reply and reinstalled Ubuntu. But, this time, there is no option of Windows 8 in startup(I'd preinstalled Windows). Then I reinstalled Windows, and completely uninstalled Ubuntu. I am glad to get rid of Linux and start to use Windows again! But, anyway thank you for the reply!

Comment: You must've overwritten Ubuntu over Windows instead of doing a side by side installation, but always happy to help!